# Help with getting started building an ASP.NET website using VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

Ok, I want to build a web site using ASP.Net.  My web development skills are very small. However I have used C# a fair bit for some fairly intermediate level work (lists, dictionaries, custom classes etc)

The site I want to build will run on an intranet, and I'll be using the AD to get the current users information.

This information will be cross checked with an MS SQL 2008 database (that already exists on the network) to determine what links they can see.

Other parts of the site will allow the User Table to be viewed and modified if the current user is an admin, and have new users added.

So, what is the best way to do this?  I've done some playing and basically confused myself with all the options available..

For example, I can create a **New Project**, which gives me options like Web Application, MVC2 Web App, MVC3 Web App, Empty Web App, Dynamic Data Entities Web App, Data Linq to SQL Web App, and then some Server controls.

But then I can also go for the **New Web Site**, which has Web Site, Web Site (Razor), Empty Web Site, Dynamic Data Entities Web Site, Dynamic Data Linq Web Site..

There are too many options!?!?!? And I don't understand what the difference is between them all..

What do people suggest I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried following some of the [MSDN Beginner Developer Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx) stuff?  They have a module on [Beginning Website Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308787.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

May be I am not answering to the point, but my 2cents. Why don't you go for Sharepoint development in this case. You can use Sharepoint site (having inbuilt AD support too) and develop custom webparts (like the part which queries SQL Server 2008). The advantage of using this is that you can merge the feature in intranet site (if you got one already using Sharepoint), and you can learn new stuffs too. Even it will be quick one and if in future, you want to use the Intranet site for different things, it's easily extensible with minimal fuss.

Comment: +1... Agree with DotNetInfo - what you described seems to be covered by basic SharePoint functionality. Getting security right is non-trivial task. If you decide to go custom route code - consider MVC as more testable platform, also Web Forms may be easier to start with.

Comment: @Alexei, yeah mate, the reason I prefer Sharepoint is because of it's extensibility. I haven't got much exposure to it but know the way Sharepoint integrates with all the MS systems like Office, TFS, etc etc, I would recommend it, but then in developers point of view, I would love to code it in MVC and learn new features. One of the bad thing about Sharepoint is the configuration that comes with it and then the developer basically turns into the supporter of Sharepoint system.

Comment: Hey guys, after watching a video about the differences, i've decided to go with Web Forms..

Comment: Hi Matt, that's not a bad alternative either. I guess if you have to deliver it in strict and quick deadline, I would go with Web Forms rather than MVC. Just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good tutorials for MVC here http://www.asp.net/mvc.

I suggest if you are building a web site to use MVC as it seems like the latest and greatest from MS at this time.  My personal opinion tho.

You would want to just start with New Project.

Comment: ooo just found this http://www.asp.net/general/videos/choosing-the-right-programming-model  I'll watch it and report back.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a lot of things to look at and  there a are a few ways to tackle this.  First all all just stick to New Web Site for now.

First things is to know if this is an intranet or internet?

it seems like it since you want to use AD, that it is an internal app.

Although there are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. I Think the following would be the easiest to implement.

1) Enable digest authentication
2) Set a IE group policy to the User authentication policy to Automatically logon only to intranet  - This way people dont get confused to what they enter.
3) Create groups for each type of user in AD
4) Separate each functionality into different folders.
5) Set the web.config for permissons to the appororiate directories.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt provided a link to a useful video ("[Choosing the right programming model](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/choosing-the-right-programming-model)"). In it, Microsoft's Scott Hanselman describes the distinguishing characteristics of the three primary ASP paths: ASP.NET Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC, or ASP.NET Web Pages. Here's the main bullet points from that presentation:

ASP.NET Web Forms:

> - Familiar control- and event-based programming model
> - Controls encapsulate HTML, JS and CSS
> - Rich UI controls included - datagrids, charts, AJAX (common tasks available out-of-the-box)
> - Browser differences handled for you
> - SharePoint builds on Web Forms (so, useful if you want to be a SharePoint dev)

ASP.NET MVC:

> - Feels comfortable for many traditional web developers
> - Total control of HTML markup (controls not provided; good grasp of HTML required)
> - Supports Unit testing, TDD and Agile methodologies
> - Encourages more prescriptive applications
> - Extremely flexible and extensible

ASP.NET Web Pages:

> - Easy to pick up and learn (similar to PHP or classic ASP)
> - Inline scripting model with Razor and C# or VB.NET
> - Simplified model with Top-to-bottom execution
> - Full control over your HTML
> - Friendly Helper syntax (encapsulated functionality, similar to Web Forms controls) makes extending your apps easy

All these models are built on common ASP libraries, so there is considerable overlap, and a fairly straightforward path to migrate an app from one model to another.